# Azure AD B2C Authentication with Xamarin.Forms Not working

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

For almost a week now I have been trying to implement Authentication in a Xamarin.Forms(Android, iOS and Windows) Project to no avail. All the instructions and guides are either out of date, not clear or not functioning.

This [Article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/azure-ad-b2c/) from Xamarin was last updated in August 2016 while the MSAL has changed making this article obsolete. in this article they make use of **PlatformParameters** which has been replaced by **UIParent**.

This [Example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) from Azure AD B2C documentation page from after implementing has **UIRequiredException** as calling **AcquireTokenSilentAsync** is not functioning since as at that time there is no user present.

This is getting really frustrating and would appreciate assistance or some step by step to implement this. All am trying to do is enable Authentication and Authorization for my Xamarin.Forms App and API Endpoint. Any pointer to good working code would be appreciated.

It would be helpful if there is an official updated guide or Video tutorial to help with this.

Comment: Which platform do you use?
I've managed to have the sample build and work on my Windows 10 machine with the creator update using Visual Studio 2017 and changing the following lines in the UserDetailsClientUWP.csproj file:


    **<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x64</Platform>**

    **<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.15063.0</TargetPlatformVersion>**
   **<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10586.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>**

Comment: Also I was using my MSA (Microsoft Account). Which social account are you trying with?

Comment: Am trying to make it work in a  Xamarin.Forms. project. Am also using my Microsoft account. I don't think it's an issue with the account. Maybe you should share your solution.

Comment: What I think would help is for Either Xamarin or the Azure AD B2C team to put together a demo on channel 9 or MVA  shoeing how to successfully use Azure AD B2C in a Xamarin.Forms project

Comment: At this point am almost giving up on B2C to rolling out our own implementation of Identity Server which I believe is what B2C is using.

Answer (score 1):

had exactly the same issue with using this project for a demo.
Use this version: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/

It is the updated version with MSAL 2.4 preview. Its working on all samples/droid/ios/uwp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much fresher sample on how to get this done (as of June 20,2017 )
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native

Comment: I have already tried this solution if you check my question the link is same.

Comment: This particular solution gives **UIRequiredException** as calling **AcquireTokenSilentAsync**

Answer (score 0):

We have had issues with the same example. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native

I have pretty much given up and I am looking at other solutions now.

Comment: I can identify with that, we are at the same point. @jeremy lets link up and find some alternative. its sad that Xamarin.Forms and the Azure AD B2C team can not come up with a working sample.